# get return type without execution of method

Tags: java, performance, methods, compiler-errors

i have tried to make some web research, but i haven't find any answer, i would like to get immediately the return statement without the execution of the method that give it. (it run before)

```
 public static int totalIncome (String [][]field) {
      
      int sum = 0;  
      sum += chairPrice (field); // here get the number without run the method
          return sum;
          
  }
```

i can't post all the code of the project i am working, i am stuck to get all the ticket sold and i was thinking this was a good way, but isn't working because it run the method again.
any idea how to do this is welcome.
i remove some method beuse it did't let me post it all, i can't even post the method chairPrice.
StackOverflow say there is too much code in my post, i tried to share all the code by codeshare,
https://codeshare.io/kmRQWV

Comment: Stack Overflow shows a preview of your post before you submit. Please actually look at it to avoid submitting posts with broken formatting. The more effort you put in to your question, the more effort people to be willing to put in to answer it.

Comment: What is your chairPrice method doing, and why can't it be run more than once? That would be helpful to know. But it seems like the solution would be to store the result to a variable, and check that variable before calling chairPrice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way, in Java, to say "I already called this method, give me the value that was returned last time."  You must explicitly store a variable somewhere to hold the value.

That said, from your code, it doesn't look like you can't call `chairPrice` because it's already been called before, but because some other state has changed.  You will need to figure out the problem in your logic.

Comment: I have place a link on code share with all my code, so if this logic is wrong i need to find an other way maybe can you have a look?